# Polygon area calculation returning 0.0 QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, area

[image]

I am trying to calculate the areas of these 12 individual polygons.

However, when I run the area calculation, two of the polygons return 0.0 - whereas the calculation works for the other 10?

Why is this? I am using the coordinate system -  EPSG:4326 - WGS 84

Comment: So your area is 0.0 square degree - which is a) not surprising, since your areas are rather small and b) bollocks, since you can measure areas in degree. You need to reproject your layer to any fitting UTM-zone.

Comment: I reprojected to a UTM zone and got the result - thanks. If you add this comment as an answer I'll accept

Comment: `$area` use the project ellipsoid, which is likely the wrong one in your case. Also note that the other polygon area seems really big, pointing again to a completely wrong computation (not just the fault of 1 or 2 polygons). --> `project / properties / general / measurements`